# Почему простые типы преобразуются c помощью GSON, а пользовательские нет?

Tags: android, java, json

```
String json = gson.toJson(decision); //все нормально, 
json= gson.toJson(identity); //Вылетает исключение. В чем проблема?
```

`decision` - тип `boolean`

`identity` - тип `my_Class`

Comment: Как ни удивительно, но [документация][1] содержит ответы на ваши вопросы.

  [1]: https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonSerializer.html

Comment: я, конечно, не сильно знаком с Java, но думаю, что этот класс, отвечающий за сериализацию, вряд ли может знать, каким именно образом он должен сериализовать пользовательские типы, если вы как-либо не указали это сами

Comment: Во-первых, как уже было отмечено в первом комментарии, есть документация. Во-вторых, оформляйте вопрос правильно: какое исключение, стек трейс, код вашего пользовательского типа, как вызываете сериализацию.

Comment: перефразирую комментарии выше:    
А от куда GSON знает, как сериализировать ваш класс?    
Немного погуглив, или почитав документацию, вы спокойно сможете научить GSON обрабатывать и ваши собственные классы.